# Create column that sums the last x occurrences of another column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to create a new column, lets call it "HomeForm", that is the sum of the last 5 values of "FTHG" for each of the entries in the "HomeTeam" column.

Say for Team 0, the idea would be to populate the cell on the new column with the sum of the last 5 values of "FTHG" that correspond to Team 0. The table is ordered by date.

How can it be done in Python?

```
        HomeTeam  FTHG   HomeForm
Date                
136          0     4
135          2     0
135          4     2
135          5     0
135          6     1
135         13     0
135         17     3
135         18     1
134         11     4
134         12     0
128          1     0
128          3     0
128          8     2
128          9     1
128         13     3
128         14     1
128         15     0
127          7     1
127         16     1
126         10     1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please give an example of what you want to do. Furthermore there is only one team `0` row in the data?

Comment: Sorry, I realise the result needed a merge rather than a reassignment (otherwise the result was right, but misaligned). Take a look now, should make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll `groupby` on `HomeTeam` and perform a `rolling` `sum` here, summing for a minimum of 1 period, and maximum of 5.

First, define a function -

```
def f(x):
     return x.shift().rolling(window=5, min_periods=1).sum()
```

This function performs the rolling sum of the previous 5 games (hence the `shift`). Pass this function to `dfGroupBy.transform` -

```
df['HomeForm'] = df.groupby('HomeTeam', sort=False).FTHG.transform(f)
df

      HomeTeam  FTHG  HomeForm
Date                          
136          0     4       NaN
135          2     0       NaN
135          4     2       NaN
135          5     0       NaN
135          6     1       NaN
135         13     0       NaN
135         17     3       NaN
135         18     1       NaN
134         11     4       NaN
134         12     0       NaN
128          1     0       NaN
128          3     0       NaN
128          8     2       NaN
128          9     1       NaN
128         13     3       0.0
128         14     1       NaN
128         15     0       NaN
127          7     1       NaN
127         16     1       NaN
126         10     1       NaN
```

If needed, fill the NaNs with zeros and convert to integer -

```
df['HomeForm'] = df['HomeForm'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: @coldspeed Thanks for that! Does exactly what I had in mind. My only problem, is when I merge back to the original dataframe, bacause in reality my dataframe has 20 something columns, the new "HomeForm" column is not being added. Any way around that?

Also, what I don't understand is why when I print the table j, it only as 3 colmuns ("HomeTeam","Date" and "HomeForm") when in my case the "df" dataframe has 20 something columns.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Also, if I understand correctly this will including the result of the own game in the "HomeForm" column. The idea would be to include only the previous 5 games, i.e. not the result of the current game would be unknown. Is there a way to apply an offset to the data?

Comment: @Miguel Understood, see edit. I think my revised method should satisfy all your follow up questions, in addition to possibly being faster and more concise.

Comment: @COLDSEED Awesome, thanks so much! This really nails it in a couple lines of code, and it's really easy to apply to other parameters!
Also, I'm not this is the correct place to discuss and I'm just starting out, but if you're interested in machine learning in sports data/analysis would be good to keep in touch.

Comment: @Miguel You're welcome. If you have any questions, shoot me an email (it's in my profile). The easiest thing to do would be ask a question on SO and link me to it, I'm always ready to answer queries in the Q&A format. Cheers and happy coding :-)